# VB6 CSV search visualbasic

Tags: arrays, csv, vb6, evaluate

I have a .csv file that has 100 rows and 8 columns. Each row looks like something below

```
0,0,0,0,0,0,0,5 

0,1,0,0,1,0,0,6
```

I need to evaluate each field.  If the field = 1 (between rows 1 and 7), I have to write the 8th column value for that row to a text box, if the field = 0 write nothing for that row.

I am very confused on how to evaluate each field.

Comment: I suggest using a 2 dimension array `Dim aryFileData(100, 8) As Integer`, then reading your data into it. If you are asking how to do it, you need to make an effort first. What do you have, or where are you having trouble?

Answer (score 2):

I use ADO with the Jet-Driver. It's very easy an the result of the import is a ADO.Recordset which you can easily navigate through.

```
Dim cnCSV As ADODB.Connection
Set cnCSV = New ADODB.Connection
cnCSV.ConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" & Chr(34) & lFilePath & Chr(34) & ";Extended Properties=" & Chr(34) & "text;HDR=Yes;FMT=Delimited" & Chr(34) & ";"
cnCSV.Open

Dim p_ImportRst As ADODB.Recordset
Set p_ImportRst = New ADODB.Recordset
lstrSQL = "SELECT * FROM [" & lFileName & "]"
Set p_ImportRst = cnCSV.Execute(lstrSQL)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an approach that should work.  Pseudo-code-ish...

```
dim vData() as variant   
dim nHandle as integer
dim sTextLine as string 
nHandle = FreeFile
open "c:\filename.csv" for input as nHandle 

Do While Not EOF(nHandle)
    Line Input #nHandle, sTextLine '// Read line into variable.

    ' break up the line into multiple pieces
    vData = split(sTextLine, ",")

    ' your criteria here
    if vData(0) = 0 then ...
    if vData(1) = ...

Loop
Close #nHandle
```

Answer (score 0):

Use "split"

"Splits a string into separate elements based on a delimiter (such as a comma or space) and stores the resulting elements in a zero-based array"

http://www.vb6.us/tutorials/vb-string-array-functions-split-join-filter

Creates a variable size array.  Use lbound and ubound to get the size of that, do for loop and add numbers together.